# C# Newtonsoft JSON: deserialize & skip object name

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
{"AE":{"amount":"0.00000000","value":"0.00000000"},
"AR":{"amount":"0.00000000","value":"0.00000000"},
"BC":{"amount":"0.09670332","value":"3.74814004"}}
```

And a class that looks like this:

```
internal class Balance {
    internal float amount;
    internal float value;
}
```

I'm trying to read it in with:

```
private static List<Balance> Balances = new List<Balances>();
Balances = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Balance>>(json);
```

... but I'm not really interested in the names of the objects (AE, AR, BC etc). How should I deserialize the input to either discard these names or stuff them someplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the json and iterate over the parent properties. Take the Balance and ignore the property name.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
List<Balance> balances = new List<Balance>();
foreach (var item in obj.Properties())
    balances.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Balance>(obj[item.Name].ToString()));
```

In essence, you are taking the json under the parent properties (AE, AR, BC) and adding the Balance object (by deserializing it) to the list you want.

1. `obj[item.Name].ToString()` gives you the inner string for each AE, AR, BC etc
2. `JsonConvert.Deserialize` converts that string to your Balance class
3. Adds the object to the list for whatever you want to do with it.

**Issues with your Balance Class**

Another thing i noticed, you are not using `getter and setter`. Without the getter and setter, you wont be able to get any values.

Also, naming convention dictates the variable names start with a capital letter. You can use JsonProperty to define the names that would be in the json.

```
internal class Balance
{
    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your *json* contains a `Dictionary<string, Balance>`.

If you just want to extract all the values, use this:

```
Balances = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Balance>>(json).Values.ToList();
```

This will deserialize into the `Dictionary<string, Balance>` and then get the `List<Balance>` with the values you're looking for.